# Conformal covariant derivative of a scalar

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differentiation

Suppose that I have a metric $g_{ij}$ with covariant derivative $\nabla_{j}$ and another metric, $\gamma_{ij}$, with covariant derivative $D_{j}$ that is conformally related to $g_{ij}$ as $\gamma_{ij} = \psi^{-4}g_{ij}$.

I am confused how $\nabla^j K$ and $D^j K$, with $K$ a scalar, are related. Evidently, I think that $\nabla^{j}K = \partial^{j}K = D^{j}K$ as $K$ is a scalar. However, then the following must be wrong:
\begin{equation*}
    \nabla^{i}K = g^{ij}\nabla_{j}K = \psi^{-4}\gamma^{ij}D_{j}K = \psi^{-4}D^{i}K
\end{equation*}
I don't see where I am going wrong in this reasoning. Someone who can point it out for me?

Comment: The usual covariant derivative is with the lower indices. Those should coincide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All covariant derivatives agree on scalars, i.e., it is true that $\nabla_j K = D_j K$.  But note that these are the *lowered-index* versions that agree, not the raised-index versions.  So your second line of reasoning is closer to correct:  if you define $D^i \equiv \gamma^{ij} D_j$, you will have $\nabla^i K \neq D^i K$ unless $\psi = 1$.

That said, it is worth being careful with these definitions when dealing with multiple metrics, and actually explicitly writing out when you're using one (or both) of your metrics to raise & lower indices.  Otherwise, you run the risk of doing "natural" operations in your expressions that aren't actually true.  For example, if you define the operator $D^i$ as above (rather than as $D^i = g^{ij} D_j$), then you will have $$g_{ij} D^j K = g_{ij} \gamma^{jk} D_k K \neq D_i K.$$  But it is altogether too easy to erroneously replace the first expression with the last based on everything you've learned about index notation.  A better practice (in my opinion) would be to simply write out $\gamma^{ij} D_j K$ explicitly if you need to use this object, which is a pain in the moment but leads to less frustration in the long run.